# Creating custom Router class in Angular leads to exception

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-dependency-injection

I want to override the function `navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras): Promise<boolean>` of Router to always set `queryParamsHandling` to `true` in the `NavigationExtras`.

Therefore I implemented following class:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MmosRouter extends Router {

    constructor(
        rootComponentType: Type<any>,
        urlSerializer: UrlSerializer,
        contexts: ChildrenOutletContexts,
        location: Location_2,
        injector: Injector,
        compiler: Compiler,
        @Inject(ROUTES) config: Route[][]
    ) {
        super(rootComponentType, urlSerializer, contexts, location, injector, compiler, flatten(config));
    }


    navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras): Promise<boolean> {
        extras = { ...extras, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' };
        return super.navigate(commands, extras);
    }
}
```

Because I want to inject the class through a components constructor I have to add the class to `providers` in `app.module.ts`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  {
    provide: Router,
    useFactory: (rootComponentType: Type<any>, urlSerializer: UrlSerializer, contexts: ChildrenOutletContexts, location: Location_2, injector: Injector, config: Route[][]) => {
      return new MmosRouter(rootComponentType, urlSerializer, contexts, location, injector, config);
    },
    deps: [ApplicationRef, UrlSerializer, ChildrenOutletContexts, Location_2, Injector, Compiler, ROUTES]
  },
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [...],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(service: ApmService) {}
}
```

For my information, that should be everything to get this to work.

However, whenever I start the application, I get following `NullInjectionError`:

```
core.mjs:9171 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[MmosRouter -> Function -> Function -> Function]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for Function!
  at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:8191:27)
  at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8618:33)
  at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8618:33)
  at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8618:33)
  at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:4782:33)
  at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:4786:12)
  at Object.MmosRouter_Factory [as factory] (mmosRouter.ts:17:24)
  at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:8719:35)
  at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8607:33)
  at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:13811:36)
```

(line 17, mentioned in the error, is the class signature of `MmosRouting`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem was `Type<any>` in the constructor of `MmosRouter`.**

Because `Type` is a `FunctionConstructor` and that interface has some properties with type `Function`, I think angular had problems to provide them when I wanted to inject my custom router.

So the Solution is removing the parameter `rootComponentType: Type<any>` from the constructor and pass `AppComponent` into the `super(...)` in the body. And then you also don't need them in the `providers` in `app.module.ts`.

So consider changing:

**Custom Router:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MmosRouter extends Router {

  constructor(
    //remove rootComponentType: Type<any>
    ...
  ) {
    super(AppComponent, ...);
  }


  navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras): Promise<boolean> {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to inject MmosRouter somewhere, and there is nothing that is provided by that token, and angular tries to resolve tokens from constructor parameters.

try

```
{
    provide: MmosRouter,
    useFactory: (rootComponentType: Type<any>, urlSerializer: UrlSerializer, contexts: ChildrenOutletContexts, location: Location_2, injector: Injector, config: Route[][]) => {
      return new MmosRouter(rootComponentType, urlSerializer, contexts, location, injector, config);
    },
    deps: [ApplicationRef, UrlSerializer, ChildrenOutletContexts, Location_2, Injector, Compiler, ROUTES]
  },
  {
    provide: Router,
    useExisting: MmosRouter
   }
```

this way your app would know how to construct `MmosRouter` and will provide same instance in place of `Router`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that won't work either. It doesn't even render the websites content. The exception now is: `NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for Function!`

Comment: it seems you should skip the `Compiler` in deps config(there is no compiler in usual builds). also most probably ApplicationRef is not a valid argument for the `rootComponentType`, but that is the issue that you should get somewhere after

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the below code block!

So `app.module.ts` will not contain the providers with the `useFactory` object!

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [...],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(service: ApmService) {}
}
```

You can simplify you service to the below code, where you import router and call the router method, just with the extra params, this will make your code less complex and more maintainable!

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MmosRouter {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }


    navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras): Promise<boolean> {
        extras = { ...extras, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' };
        return this.navigate(commands, extras);
    }
}
```

The above code will do the same thing!